# DRF serializer data input format (json instead of request.data)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I created an api endpoint using DRF but the serializers have some really deep nested relationships and therefore cannot render out the serializer as form easily (for html).

I therefore tried to create simple Django forms capture the user input and parse it into some complex nested jsons my own. However the serializers just cannot seem to accept normal json.

Is it possible to make the serializer accept data in json format instead of "request.data"?

If not what are the alternative ways of rendering forms in html? ( I thought of rendering out the serializer manually inside the template but I can't find any resources on how to do so)

Comment: `render out the serializer as form`, `serializers cannot accept json`, elaborate please. Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

- Deeply nested data sounds like it might be challenging to maintain.
  Is it possible that the models are being overly specialized?
- "Is it possible to make the serializer accept data in json format
  instead of request.data?" I'm sure this can be figured out by using
  the source code, but I'm going to guess no because then there would
  be no need for the API object to parse the JSON data.
- "If not what are the alternative ways of rendering forms in html? ( I
  thought of rendering out the serializer manually inside the template
  but I can't find any resources on how to do so)"
  I'm not sure how others are using DRF, but I mostly use it so that I can obtain the data via a REST api and use the o-so-flexible ReactJs

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am quite new to DRF and webdev in general. May I ask is ReactJs the conventional way to obtain data via REST api? I thought ReactJs is only used to build interactive user interface but nothing else. It seems more logical to handle these stuff in the backend.

Comment: javasacript fetch and axios are the conventional ways by which developers obtain data via REST api. After retrieving it as JSON, they pass the data back to the UI framework(ReactJs/Vue/Angular)